# Playing multiple videos in two different views with Flowplayer

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, flowplayer

> Consider I have two separate players in two separate views in DOM.
>   Each player gets video file asynchronous from my database by unique
>   ID. So for first video player it works fine. But I am not sure about
>   doing the same thing with my second player which is in second view.

```
<div class="View_1">
<div data-swf="<?php echo base_url();?>scripts/flowplayer.swf"
      class="flowplayer no-toggle play-button"
       data-ratio="0.625" data-embed="false">
      <video id="myPlayer_1">
         <source type="video/webm" src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm"/>
      </video>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="View_2">
<div data-swf="<?php echo base_url();?>scripts/flowplayer.swf"
      class="flowplayer no-toggle play-button"
       data-ratio="0.625" data-embed="false">
      <video id="myPlayer_2">
         <source type="video/webm" src="http://stream.flowplayer.org/bauhaus/624x260.webm"/>
      </video>
   </div>
</div>
```

> In Javascript part I do so:

```
$(".filmStackPlay").live("click",function(){
        VideoUrl="http://content.unibox.tj/movies/"+$(this).attr("file");
         var api = flowplayer(0);
       api.load([
        { mp4: VideoUrl}]);
        $(".videoPlayerContainer").show();
        $(".videoPlayerContainer").animate({top:"0px"},300);
        $(".videoOverlay").show();       
});
```

> I unload the player in first view by this method:

```
function UnloadVideo(){
        var api = flowplayer(0);
        api.unload();
        $(".videoPlayerContainer").hide();
        $(".videoPlayerContainer").css("top","-500px");
        $(".videoOverlay").hide();
}
```

> The question is how to load video to the second view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load the first player you do the following

```
var api = flowplayer(0);
api.load();
```

To load the second player you quite simply increase the index by one.

```
var api = flowplayer(1);
api.load();
```

Comment: Your answer is correct bro. I have solved it 4 hours ago. But thanks. I will accept it for your afford. ;)